# Make AI do a specific build in YABOT?

Tags: starcraft-2

I want to practice against various builds (things like roach builds, zerg rushes, DT rushes, etc.) so i can make and refine counter-builds for them. Is it possible to get the AI to do them consistently with YABOT?

Comment: I was wondering about this too, ideally you can then test a build you made against a lot of other established builds and change it accordingly. Rather than going online and having to wait quite some matches just to test if you can counter an annoying build you're having problems with...

Comment: I know I discussed this in another thread, but the AI for YABOT is broken right now.  Given the lack of response from the author I'm unsure what the odds of this being rectified is.

Comment: I don't think we need a specific tag for YABOT. Wouldn't "Custom Maps" be better (the tag already exists)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of [YABOT 1.3](http://www.sc2mapster.com/maps/yabot/files/20-v1-3/):

- Added Green Tea AI 0.57 back in
- Added checkpoint system (-sc and -lc)
- Added attack waves back in
- Added a new demo mode to watch AI perform builds
- Round end time now set using slider control
- Objective text updates with time when completed
- Minor bug fixes

I believe this should provide the resource you are looking for.