# How do I play vs. the AI and choose the strategy for the AI?

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-terran

When playing Terran, I'm getting by butt kicked by mass Mutalisks.

I want to practice that. In previous versions of Starcraft 2 I could choose a strategy for the AI (like Air).

How do I do it in the current version?

Comment: i think it should be possible to crate a custom game with these options. need to check it when i get home.

Comment: Hey man, not an exact answer but maybe you can find some useful information [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10870/make-ai-do-a-specific-build-in-yabot/12066). Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a game against KI if you go to Custom -> Melee
Create a lobby, add A.I. enemies and choose a race. The Button next to it lets you choose a tactic for that a.i.

[image: Menu]
[image: Game]